# How to use JavaScript variable in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        $("#one" + i).html("<?php echo $arr["+i+"]["+x+"] ?>");
        $("#two" + i).html("<?php echo $arr["+i+"]["+x+1+"] ?>");
    };
};

</script>
```

No error is showed, but content also not.

How can I use the increment variable of JavaScript in PHP code?

Thanks

Comment: Just to say, this line for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) is egual than simply write x = 0 and delete the inner loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may make your PHP-array accessible to JS(store it as a js-variable) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        $("#one" + i).html(arr[i][x]);
        $("#two" + i).html(arr[i][x+1]);
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your loop runs from 0 to 4, but there are only 3 items. You'll get an error when i comes to 3(arr[3] doesn't exist). See my updated code, use `arr.length` instead of the fixed 5 to avoid this error.

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot do this.**

Javascript runs on the client, which is *after* all PHP code has executed.

Why don't you write the loop in PHP instead? For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++) {
        printf('$("#one%s").html("%s");', $i, $arr[$i][$x]);
        printf('$("#two%s").html("%s");', $i, $arr[$i][$x + 1]);
    };
};
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Jon, i am totally confused. The only thing that i know is that i have a group of divs like `#one0`, `#two0`, `#one1`, `#one1`, ... and none of them changes the text to display. The other thing that i know is: echo `$arr[0][0]` or `$arr[0][1]` returns a value

Comment: @Daniel: There are so many unknowns in this situation, and you are obviously at the beginner stage, that it's really difficult to tell what's wrong. The code should work, but you may have some issues with setting up jQuery right. What about writing the code to change the contents literally (forgetting about `$arr`)? Does that work? What about `$arr`? Does it have enough elements?

Comment: the problem is the word sprintf, must be printf. With this change also works now. thanks

Comment: @Daniel: Doh. Intended to write `echo sprintf`, then realized that just `printf` is the same, and made only half of the edit. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I try to give you a short question..althought it may be very long.
PHP it's a **Server-side** scripting language, while javascript it's a **Client-side** one.

That's mean that the php code is interpreted and executeted in the server (e.g. Apache), and the javascript code is executed inside the browser itself.

So, there is no way you can execute php code inside of your brower. 
for the code you have written you can simpli transform the two `for` javascript iteration in php. If you actually need to print something in php given a javascript variable you should do an AJAX request to a php page that recive your javascript value and returns back the php-calculated values you need.

Please have a look at those references as a start:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: This is the only right answer here, I don't get it why the other answers got so many up votes!?

Answer (score 0):

`<?php` is interpreted by the php interpreter. If you don't have this block in an actual php file, then that means you are executing in the context of the browser. The browser doesn't know about php, only your web server. Thus, the browser will interpret `<?php` as an HTML element, which doesn't exist.

You need to move your entire block into a php file, like so:

```
myFile.php
==========
    <?php
        $arr = array(...);
        $arrLen = count($arr);
        $output = '<script type="text/javascript">';
        for ($i=0; $i<$arrLen; $i++) {  // notice this is in php, not js
            $output .= '$("#one"'.$i.').html("'.$arr[$i][0].'");';
            $output .= '$("#two"'.$i.').html("'.$arr[$i][1].'");';
        }
        $output .= '</script>';
        echo $output;
    ?>
```