# How to get jQuery variable with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have defined a jQuery variable

```
var user_id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
```

and i want to get the user name like this:

```
alert({!! \App\User::findOrFail(user_id)->name !!});
```

Is this even possible?

i get this error:

[image]
How can i get the user name through jQuery variable??

#### update

i did this

```
var user_id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
{{ var_dump($user_id) }}
```

and i get this error:

[image]

Comment: in laravel blade template you used some thing like this ..... alert({{$test->name}});... and its working

Comment: yes but this is dynamic, so I can't fix the variable because there are a lot of different users

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856340/how-to-use-javascript-variable-in-php)

Comment: i can't solve my problem with that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your user data from the controller to the view. In the view you can pass is to your javascript.

Example:

In your controller

`$userName = \App\User::findOrFail(user_id)->name;
return view('blade...', ['user_name' => $userName);`

In your blade

`<script>var userName = '{{ $userName }}' </script>`

If you need more information about the user, you can pass the user to the blade and call the name like so: `{{ $user->name }}.

If the user is dynamic you can maybe look to make a simple api-like-endpoint to load the data of the user.

Comment: yes i know I can return a view with php variable, but I need somehow to get PHP inside view to work with javascript variable...

Comment: I don't think it works the other way around. You can't make php work with javascript-variables. PHP is handled on the server-side and javascript on the client-side.

Comment: Yes, you were right this is not possible and all of your answers are wrong....this can only be done with ajax!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in view. Something like this

```
<script> var name = <?php echo \App\User::findOrFail($user_id)->name ?>
</script>
```

And then use name variable in your javascript, offcorse yous shold at first get $user_id.

Comment: Yess that is exactly what i am trying to do....and my question is how can i get the $user_id from a html div id? Actually i get the variable...but i can't work with it because blade doesn't see that variable

Comment: For example you can save it in url, or in cookie.